# Can not access a member of class "com.ABC$XYZ" with modifiers "synchronized"

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes, synchronized, illegalaccessexception

I'm trying to retrieve synchronized method using reflection API.

Sample code snippet given below:

```
class ABC {
    class XYZ {
        synchronized List methodOfXYZ() {
            System.out.println("Im in Method");
            // do sum stuff
            return <Obj-List>;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the runtime exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class "com.TestReflection" can not access a member of class "com.ABC$XYZ" with modifiers "synchronized".
```

Comment: Show us the code that throws the exception.

Comment: The `TestReflection` class does not have visibility of the `methodOfXYZ()` method (due to visibility modifiers and package structure of your actual code). You can get around this by either doing `myMethod.setAccessible(true)` before calling `myMethod.invoke(...)` or fixing your package structure so that your reflection code has visiblity of the method you're trying to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public Class ABC
{
    public Class XYZ 
    {
       public synchronized List methodOfXYZ()
       {
          System.out.println("Im in Method");
         // do sum stuff
         return <Obj-List>;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mckeown and Sam.. This class ABC is provided in client API. So I cant change it. one correction in the class is : public Class ABC
{
    Class XYZ implements Runnable
    {
       synchronized List methodOfXYZ()
       {
          System.out.println("Im in Method");
         // do sum stuff
         return <Obj-List>;
        }
     }
 }